# Passing a single item and getting a prediction

Tags: r, naive-bayes

I have completed a demo of a naive Bayes classifier for predicting whether an SMS message is spam or ham.

My question is, how can I use this in a practical manner?  It appears I would have to completely retrain the classifier every time there is a new message.

Ideally, I would like to simply pass in a new string to a method and the output would tell me the probability of it's being spam or not.

Here is how I am currently predicting:

```
# a lot of text manipulation to get the string values into a 
# suitable format precede these lines

sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(sms_train, sms_raw_train$type)

sms_test_pred <- predict(sms_classifier, sms_test)
```

The results:

```
Total Observations in Table:  1390 


             | actual 
   predicted |       ham |      spam | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
         ham |      1204 |        31 |      1235 | 
             |    16.148 |   106.504 |           | 
             |     0.998 |     0.169 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
        spam |         3 |       152 |       155 | 
             |   128.660 |   848.596 |           | 
             |     0.002 |     0.831 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |      1207 |       183 |      1390 | 
             |     0.868 |     0.132 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

**Edit for clarification:**

I initially have 5k rows like this:

```
type,text
ham,Hope you are having a good week. Just checking in
ham,K..give back my thanks.
ham,Am also doing in cbe only. But have to pay.
```

I then perform a number of manipulations using `tm` package to be able to run the naive Bayes classifier to predict the type of the unseen data based on the text.

I would like to simply pass a string to a method to utilize my existing classifier without having to retrain the entire thing, like so:

```
classifyNewItem <- function(text) {
    # run new item against classifier here
}
```

**Is this how this is generally done?  What is the preferred method of utilizing a classifier in a real world scenario such as a spam filter?**

Comment: Take a look at the [`save`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/save.html) and [`load`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/load.html) functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use your classifier, it has to be trained, hence, yes, you have to train a classifier every time you have something to predict.
But you are absolutely right, in a high speed (production) environment, it may not be very suitable to have to train a classifier every time it has to predict something.
The only solution is to keep the classifier in memory or save it to disk, ready to predict whatever you want to through at it.

The solution is:
You train your classifier with your 5k training samples. Then store it somewhere using the `save` function. Then create a function that takes your SMS string as input. The function loads the classifier from the disk, classifies the string, outputs the result.

Thanks @Affine for the R functions

Bonus info: scikit-learn is a popular module for machinelearning in Python, which has methods for storing the trained classifiers (using pickle) to disk/database. Very useful if you have something to predict every now and then but don't want to retrain a classifier every time. We use this when prediction is only needed every 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, that's good info.  It looks like something like this may work; I just don't know if it's the best approach for this circumstance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863942/save-a-random-forest-object

Comment: Updated the answer..